# How to apply colour to a triangle with opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I am trying to create a simple program with openGL. The goal is to create a triangle with colours for every vertex. The problem is that I can not figure out how to apply the colours to the triangle's vertices.

My vertex shader:

```
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec4 vertex_position;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 vertex_color;

smooth out vec4 theColor;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(vertex_position.x, vertex_position.y, vertex_position.z, 1.0);
    theColor = vertex_color;
}
```

My fragment shader:

```
#version 330

smooth in vec4 theColor;
out vec4 outColor;
void main()
{
    outColor = theColor;
}
```

main code:

```
    float vertices[] = {
                -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
                0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
                0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
                0.5f, 0.6f, 0.1f,
                0.2f, 0.6, 0.3f,
                0.1f, 0.23f, 0.78f
            };

        GLuint my_vao, my_vbo;
                glGenVertexArrays(1, &my_vao);
                glBindVertexArray(my_vao);
                glGenBuffers(1, &my_vbo);
                glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, my_vbo);
                glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
                glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
            //  glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
                glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3*sizeof(float), (void*)0);
            //  glVertexAttribPointer(3,4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_TRUE, 0, (void*)0);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glViewport(0, 0, viewport_width, viewport_height);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    swapBuffers();
```

The array vertices consists of the vertex points (first 3 vectors) and the color values (second 3 vectors). You can see my result in the following picture:

[image: Simple Triangle]

I have been trying to apply the colours with the following code:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(3,4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_TRUE, 0, (void*)0);
```

Unfortunately it does not work and I have no idea how to fix that. Can anyone help me out here?

For compiling and loading my shaders I use:

```
    std::string loadVertexShader(const char* vertexPath)
    {
        std::string vertexCode;
        std::ifstream vShaderFile;
        vShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
        try
        {
            vShaderFile.open(vertexPath);
            std::stringstream vShaderStream;
            vShaderStream << vShaderFile.rdbuf();
            vShaderFile.close();
            vertexCode = vShaderStream.str();
        }
        catch (std::ifstream::failure e)
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR::VERTEXSHADER::FILE_NOT_SUCCESFULLY_READ" << std::endl;
        }
        return vertexCode;
    }

int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        std::string vertexVal = loadVertexShader("shader/vertexshader.shader");
        const char* vShaderCode = vertexVal.c_str();
        std::string fragmentVal = loadFragmentShader("shader/fragmentshader.shader");
        const char* fShaderCode = fragmentVal.c_str();
        glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vShaderCode, NULL);
        glCompileShader(vertexShader);
        glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fShaderCode, NULL);
        glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

GLint vertexStatus;
        char vertexInfoLog[512];
        char fragmentInfoLog[512];
        glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &vertexStatus);
        GLint fragmentStatus;
        glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &fragmentStatus);

        if (!vertexStatus)
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, fragmentInfoLog);
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << fragmentInfoLog << std::endl;
        }

        if (!fragmentStatus)
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, vertexInfoLog);
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << vertexInfoLog << std::endl;
        }
```

Comment: The first parameter of `glVertexAttribPointer` should be 1 instead of 3 to match `layout(location = 1)`. You should also add the VBO with the color data.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Changing the parameter to 1 did not change anything. Doesn't the VBO my_vbo already have the color data since it gets the array vertices, which has vertex points and vertex color in it?

Comment: Oh sorry, overread that part. Assuming your data contains 3*3 floats for vertices and then 3 * 3 floats for color, the attribute pointer should be: `glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)3*3*sizeof(float))`. I'm not sure why you used unsigned byte since your data is float.

Comment: NB: it is generally a bad idea to catch C++ exceptions by value, better `catch (std::ifstream::failure const & e)`.

Comment: Ok thank you. Do you think that there might be something wrong with my loadVertexShader function? I do exactly the same with the fragment shader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, as was revealed in the discussion in comments, you don't link your program. A typical shader program setup looks like this:

```
GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(program, shader1);
glAttachShader(program, shader2);
...
glAttachShader(program, shaderN);
glLinkProgram(program); // <<<<<<<<< a-ha!
```

After that, a good idea is to check if program linkage was OK. A good example of the full shaders & program setup can be found [on OpenGL wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Compilation#Example).

After successful program linkage, you can even detach the shaders from the program (`glDetachShader`) and delete them (`glDeleteShader`) - the program is already linked, shaders are of no use now (unless you intend to attach them to another program, of course).

---

Secondly, your arguments to `glVertexAttribPointer` are slightly messed up (which is totally OK - it takes time and effort to get used to them).

```
void glVertexAttribPointer(GLuint index, GLint size, GLenum type, GLboolean normalized,
    GLsizei stride, const GLvoid * pointer);
```

- `index` is the attribute index - same as `location` as specified in shader, so for your color attribute it should be `1`.
- `size` is the attribute's dimension, i.e. number of components; supposing that you are using 3-float RGB, size should be `3`
- `type` is the actual type of the components; in you case these are floating-points too, so `GL_FLOAT`
- `stride` is the distance between attributes of adjacent vertices, which is 3 floats in your case, i.e. 12 bytes; since there's nothing in between adjacent attributes in your `vertices` array, we can actually leave this zero (both for coordinates & colors)
- `pointer` is the pointer to actual attributes data (or, in your case, offset in VBO); you are passing the same pointer to both `glVertexAttribPointer` calls, while your color values are 9 floats after the beginning of coordinate values

So, it should be

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (float const *)(nullptr) + 9);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work either. My code: 

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3*sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)(3 * 3 **sizeof(float)));

Comment: @CoderOfTheForce In what exact way doesn't it work? Is the triangle still black? What happens if you change your fragment shader `main` to e.g. `outColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);` ?

Comment: the triangle is still black. If I change the fragment shader like you said, nothing happens. It remains black.

Comment: @CoderOfTheForce Now this is very strange. Are you sure you've recompiled the project, etc? How do you compile your shader? Do you check if shader compilation succeeded?

Comment: Yes I have recompiled everything. I just edited my question. You can see my shader handling there. I get no errors from glGetShaderInfoLog()

Comment: @CoderOfTheForce Everything looks fine at this point. Please, show the program compilation code & check for OpenGL errors after rendering (`glGetError`).

Comment: @CoderOfTheForce Oh, now that's something! This is `0x0502` aka `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`. Could you check which exact OpenGL call sets the error? (put `glGetError` after each OpenGL function call and find the first non-zero result)

Comment: The problem ocurrs when I call: glUseProgram(shaderProgram). I do the following: 
int shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);

And in my rendering loop I call glUseProgram(shaderProgram) before I do anything else.

Comment: @CoderOfTheForce Oh, it looks like you've forgotten to link the program! Please, update the question with your full program compilation code, and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for being so patient with me. That fixed it. Now the triangle has the colors it should have.

Comment: @CoderOfTheForce Glad to know! I'm happy to be of service.